# react native Async Storage not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

I'm trying to make an auth process so my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
import Router from "./Router";
import ScanForm from "./components/ScanForm";

console.disableYellowBox = true;

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoggedIn: false
  };

  componentWillMount() {   
    const temp = AsyncStorage.getItem("operator");
    console.log(temp);

    if (temp !== undefined) {
      this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoggedIn) {
      return <ScanForm />;
    } else {
      return <Router />;
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

So if it's the first time that user opens the app, the `operator` is null or undefined (i tried both but no results) - (Then in the `LoginForm` i will change the `operator` to something like "john" after the user logs in).

But it's returning the `<Router />` for some reason (consider that the `isLoggedIn` must be false logically but...)

I've also tried to **setItem** in that section for testing but no results again:

```
componentWillMount() {
    AsyncStorage.setItem("operator", "John");

    const temp = AsyncStorage.getItem("operator");
    console.log(temp);
  }
```

But `console.log(temp);` says `undefined` again!

Why I can't use `setItem` and then fetch data with `getItem`?

> Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AsyncStorage is *asynchronous* :-).  The committed value isn't available until its returned promise resolves.  In exchange for this inconvenience, it won't block your JavaScript thread while the writing is underway.

If you try:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem("operator", "John").then(
   () => AsyncStorage.getItem("operator")
         .then((result)=>console.log(result))
)
```

You should get what you expect.  (This can also be accomplished using async/await as shown in the [AsyncStorage docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html)).

You don't really show us how you feed props into your app, but if you update `<App>`'s props with `isLoggedIn` when the value is updated on the `then`, your component should update accordingly.

Comment: And if the item can't be found, it will be `undefined`? - I mean when i use `getItem` for a undeclared key

Comment: Ah!  Look at the docs (linked above).  getItem also returns a promise.  Updating the answer...

Comment: What's the best way to check if the user is logged in in react native in your opinion? And also if is logged in, access his login info

Comment: As I mentioned above, you don't show us how your state is stored or how you're feeding your app; I'd store that item in a persistent data structure, that whenever updated, re-renders my component hierarchy.  In that case, just render different UI depending on whether that prop is set to logged-out, or user data.   I typically use Redux (https://redux.js.org/) and redux-react for data store.